# Error handling from adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

how is possible handle restAdapter errors from store or adapter?
Now I am using this code:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        var self = this;
        return this.store.find('item').then(function(data){
            return data;
        }, function (error){
            console.log('error');
            return [];
        });

    },
});
```

It would be better something more general. Thanks

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. But for general information sake. Ember-Data is still in development and a big plan they have is to raise error handling overall. [This blog sheds light on that.](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-data-0-13.html)

Comment: I know that. My questions is: How I would catch an error if server data-api don't responding. I make it according to my example code. But it is created only for Application Route, but I need it for every store.find().

Comment: Maybe over-ride the stores find method to alert on errors?

Answer (score 5):

Until there is some more sophisticated error handling throughout ember data, you could do something like the following to handle network errors in a cross-cutting way:

**Extend the RESTAdapter to parse errors from the xhr object**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError: function (jqXHR) {
    jqXHR = this._super(jqXHR) || {status : 'unknown'};
    var error;
    if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
      error = 'not_found';
    } else if (...) {
      ...
    } else {
      error = 'dunno';
    }
    return error;
  }
});
```

**Extend the store to publish error events when bad things happen**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  recordWasError: function (record, reason) {
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    this.trigger('error', reason);
  }
});
```

**Catch the error in your Application Route**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function () {
    this.get('store').on('error', function (error) {
      // Do something with the error
      console.error(error);
    });
  },

  ...
});
```